# Unicodeescape error while using chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Am getting the below error while executing the chromedriver using selenium in Python.

> **(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

My Code is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\a02450\Desktop\Stock\chromedriver.exe')
```

Even I used `r` in front of `C:\` am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `\U` (used for unicode strings in Python) in your string. You need to escape the `\` before that.

Replace `'C:\Users\a02450\Desktop\Stock\chromedriver.exe'` by `'C:\\Users\\a02450\\Desktop\\Stock\\chromedriver.exe'`.